# Which method to use to set variables on launch?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, launch

which is the proper method to set NSUserdefaults after launching of the app, not the first launch really, ANY launch. I need to define some flags.

viedDidLoad or viewDidAppear? I'm not sure and I want to produce clean code.

Also, which one t set the variables free? 
applicationWillTerminate? I dont want to delete the vars when like a phone call arrives, but when the user closes it by clicking the homebutton. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is the proper method to set NSUserdefaults after launching of the app, not the first launch really, ANY launch. I need to define some flags.

That sounds like a total misuse of NSUserDefaults (especially if your goal is to "produce clean code"). NSUserDefaults can certainly be used for globals, but its purpose is to persist values. Resetting those value on each launch is just the opposite of what NSUserDefaults is for.

If you are trying to set some variables on launch, then use *variables*. You can set them in `applicationDidFinishLaunching...` in your app delegate, and make them available from there (every object can see the app delegate).

> Also, which one t set the variables free? applicationWillTerminate?

There is no need to free anything. If you use real variables they will go out of existence when the app terminates (and you will give them their initial values when the app launches, as I've already explained).

Comment: thank you, i think i mixed up nsuserdefaults with sessions in webdevelopment. so the userdefaults are used to store e.g. a username, or the info how much the app was runned. stuff like that?

Comment: btw, i added "int questionCategory" to applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate and its not visible in FirstViewController. Do i have to make it global or something?

Comment: You have to make it a `@property`. Do you know Objective-C?

Comment: I do little, just started, anyway, I made it a property and did #import the AppDelegate.h in the VC i want to use the property

Comment: Excellent. It sounds like you've got it all figured out. So now you can call `[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] questionCategory]` (from any VC that does that `#import`).

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm not yet too much into objective-c and xcode but i already like it a lot. its fun building apps. but it has literally less to do with php. but thats an objective-c thing, i guess. syntax is pretty strange.

Comment: I've written a book that can help you. And it's free to read the iOS 6 edition online! http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/

Comment: I'm actually too stupid for Xcode. I dont manage to get a Backbutton in my UINavigationViewController in Xcode 5.0.2... I dont find the option in storyboard. Can you also help me with this?